# Problems Embedding PDF Byte Stream In Page

Tags: html, pdf, stream

I am generating in-memory PDF's on the server and want to send the result as a byte stream to be displayed as a PDF on a web page.  I don't seem to have everything in order as none of the major browsers will properly display the PDF.  I've tried embed, object and iframe tags but can't get it working.

Here's the embed version as copied from an IE page:

> `<`embed width="100%" height="100%"
>   src="data:application/pdf,%PDF-1.4
> %ÓôÌá
> 1 0
>   obj
> <<
> /CreationDate(D:20151030142159-07'00')
> /Title(Created
>   with PDFsharp)
> /Creator(PDFsharp 1.32.3057-g
>   (www.pdfsharp.net))
> /Producer(PDFsharp 1.32.3057-g
>   (www.pdfsharp.net))
> >>
> endobj
> 2 0
>   obj
> <<
> /Type/Catalog
> /Pages 3 0 R
> >>
> endobj
> 3
>   0 obj
> <<
> /Type/Pages
> /Count 1
> /Kids[4 0
>   R]
> >>
> endobj
> 4 0 obj
> <<
> /Type/Page
> /MediaBox[0
>   0 612 792]
> /Parent 3 0 R
> /Contents 5 0
>   R
> /Resources
> <<
> /ProcSet
>   [/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI]
> /ExtGState
> <<
> /GS0 6 0
>   R
> >>
> /Font
> <<
> /F0 8 0
>   R
> >>
> >>
> /Group
> <<
> /CS/DeviceRGB
> /S/Transparency
> /I
>   false
> /K false
> >>
> >>
> endobj
> 5 0
>   obj
> <<
> /Length
>   98
> /Filter/FlateDecode
> >>
> stream
> x+ä2T0�B]eni¤d(Tqr9pé»(¤sé»ÅÓ¸L,ôÌÍMLôÌ,BR4>
> endobj
> 7 0
>   obj
> <<
> /Type/FontDescriptor
> /Ascent 891
> /CapHeight
>   662
> /Descent -216
> /Flags 32
> /FontBBox[-547 -307 1401
>   1032]
> /ItalicAngle -16.333
> /StemV 0
> /XHeight
>   439
> /FontName/TimesNewRoman,BoldItalic
> >>
> endobj
> 8 0
>   obj
> <<
> /Type/Font
> /Subtype/TrueType
> /BaseFont/TimesNewRoman,BoldItalic
> /Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding
> /FontDescriptor
>   7 0 R
> /FirstChar 0
> /LastChar 255
> /Widths[777 777 777 777
>   777 777 777 777 777 777 777 777 777 777 777 777 777 777 777 777 777
>   777 777 777 777 777 777 777 777 777 777 777 250 389 555 500 500 833
>   777 277 333 333 500 569 250 333 250 277 500 500 500 500 500 500 500
>   500 500 500 333 333 569 569 569 500 832 666 666 666 722 666 666 722
>   777 389 500 666 610 889 722 722 610 722 666 556 610 722 666 889 666
>   610 610 333 277 333 569 500 333 500 500 443 500 443 333 500 556 277
>   277 500 277 777 556 500 500 500 389 389 277 556 443 666 500 443 389
>   348 220 348 569 777 500 777 333 500 500 1000 500 500 333 1000 556 333
>   943 777 610 777 777 333 333 500 500 350 500 1000 333 1000 389 333 722
>   777 389 610 250 389 500 500 500 500 220 500 333 747 266 500 605 333
>   747 500 399 548 299 299 333 576 500 250 333 299 299 500 750 750 750
>   500 666 666 666 666 666 666 943 666 666 666 666 666 389 389 389 389
>   722 722 722 722 722 722 722 569 722 722 722 722 722 610 610 500 500
>   500 500 500 500 500 722 443 443 443 443 443 277 277 277 277 500 556
>   500 500 500 500 500 548 500 556 556 556 556 443 500
>   443]
> >>
> endobj
> xref
> 0 9
> 0000000000 65535 f
>   
> 0000000015 00000 n 
> 0000000210 00000 n 
> 0000000258 00000
>   n 
> 0000000313 00000 n 
> 0000000568 00000 n 
> 0000000736
>   00000 n 
> 0000000779 00000 n 
> 0000000981 00000 n
>   
> trailer
> <<
> /ID[<24C49FD36FB7C74593CB248B32E8A112><24C49FD36FB7C74593CB248B32E8A112>]
> /Info
>   1 0 R
> /Root 2 0 R
> /Size
>   9
> >>
> startxref
> 2178
> %%EOF
> " type="application/pdf"
>   />

This document only contains "Hello, World!" and was sucked in straight from an actual PDF file using File.ReadAllBytes(...) in C#.

Comment: Dec 2023: I too am streaming a PDF into an <object> and Chrome is actually downloading the file but the <object> does not display it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're missing one step. The embedded PDF needs to be encoded.

The following is from a similar smallish PDF. I encoded it into base 64 by uploading the PDF to site http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp.

I then pasted the base64 result into my embedded element as follows:

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" src="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKJaWx6woxIDAgb2JqCjw8IC9UeXBlIC9DYXRhbG9nIC9QYWdlcyAyIDAgUiA+Pgpl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"/>
```

If you save the above as html then open it with a browser you should see the following one-page PDF.

[image: embedded PDF]

I'd suggest trying a similar process to encoded your PDF as base 64 and embed it as above.

Comment: This works!  Thanks!  Actually the byte stream was already in base64, but I thought I had to convert it (with atob) back to ascii.  This works just fine in Chrome and Firefox, but for some reason IE is refusing to show it.  I'll have to start going through IE options.

Comment: also tried `object` tag, giving similar 'results' on IE :-|  `<object width="100%" type="application/pdf" height="100%" data="data:application/pdf;base64,...>Sample PDF</object>`

Comment: I put it in as a new query.

Comment: I gave up.  I now put the PDF into an accessible location as a real file and just open a new tab pointing to it.

Answer (score -1):

I realize the question was about embedding a PDF using a base64 encoding, but the question is looking for a way to send an in-memory PDF to the browser using a byte stream.  I struggled for a while with this (in C#) and came up with the following code solution:

```
    [HttpGet("download/{id}/raw")]
    public ActionResult GetDownloadAttachmentRaw(long id)
    {
        var rules = BusinessRules.Rules.ExtractFrom(HttpContext);
        var attachment = rules.GetAttachment(id) ?? throw new Exception("Attachment not found");
        var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(GetFileName(attachment));
        var mimeType = attachment.MimeType ?? "application/octet-stream";
        return new FileContentResult(fileBytes, mimeType);
    }
```

When the user requests a valid PDF attachment, the file is read from the file system (into memory) and then returned to the user a FileContentResult.  This many seem obvious, but I was first using a FileStreamResult (code not shown) and the HTML  was downloading the file and not displaying it.

Again, I know this is not a direct answer to the question but I think it may be helpful to others searching for a C# solution to streaming in-memory PDFs.